# Tooltip is not displayed - winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, tooltip

I have a usercontrol2 (custom) on a form. I have defined a tooltip on the user control. The usercontrol2 has some child controls on it.

I want the tooltip to be shown when i click on a specific child control on usercontrol2. The tooltip should hide only if i click outside the child control.

The tooltip is shown when i click on the child control but is hidden once i move the mouse position. Also, when i click outside the child control and i click on the child control again, the tooltip is not shown.

The child control is named usercontrol1.

```
public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
{
    private Boolean IsToolTipShown;
    public UserControl2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WireControl(userControl11);
        InitiliseToolTip();
    }
    private void WireControl(Control cont)
    {
        cont.MouseClick += UserControlMouseClick;
        foreach (Control ctl in cont.Controls)
        {
            ctl.MouseClick += UserControlMouseClick;
            if (ctl.HasChildren) WireControl(ctl);
        }
    }
    private void UserControlMouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsToolTipShown)
        {
            string s = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                s += string.Concat(i, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            toolTip1.Show(s, userControl11);
            IsToolTipShown = true;
        }
    }
    private void InitiliseToolTip()
    {
        IsToolTipShown = false;
        toolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 0;
        toolTip1.BackColor = Color.Chartreuse;
        toolTip1.StripAmpersands = true;
        toolTip1.ToolTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        toolTip1.UseFading = false;
    }
    protected override void OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseClick(e);
        if (IsToolTipShown)
        {
            toolTip1.Hide(userControl11);
            IsToolTipShown = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but I'd suggest implementing your own, either on paint or just a label...

Comment: Internally tooltip is based around `MouseEnter`/`MouseLeave` events. I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but perhaps tooltip is not the right thing. You can try to handle additional mouse events to force tooltip, but this probably will looks ugly. I am with @Trey here, use something else, `Label` with some border inside client area is good.

Comment: I did some custom controls like this, and what I did was override the paint event, so i could just paint over any controls drawn.

Comment: There was a popup control (`ToolStripDropDown` + `ToolStripControlHost` solution, maybe [this one](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control))  for winforms which visibility you can fully control.

Comment: It worked with just a label. I'll try it with the ToosStripDropDown also.. Thanks..